# Delphi threads and variables

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-7

So this is my question , threads are so confusing for me , let's say I have 5 threads , and 50 or 100 or more sites. So as far as I've learned about threads , I can make constructor create (link:string) and start new threads with different links , but than I wold need to make as much threads as the number of links I need to parse.So how can I make variable link shared between threads , so when thread one downloads link listbox1.items[0] it tells others that number 0 is downloaded and next thread should ask what link should I download and get answer listbox1.items[1] and so on until they download all links when they should terminate.
Can anyone provide me with simple example of how can this be done. Threads are killing me :(

Comment: Your best bet is to use [OTL](http://otl.17slon.com/). However, you also need to brush up your knowledge of threading in general. You could do a lot worse than to buy and read Joe Duffy's book, Concurrent Programming on Windows. For a quick and dirty approach you can use InterlockedIncrement to increment as task counter as part of a `GetNextJob` approach. But really, this is trivial with OTL.

Comment: The accepted answer to this question has some useful discussion of logic and example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515036

Comment: Does OTL supports delphi 7 , please David tell me which books should I read , all the books I found have only 10 or 15 pages on threads and in most cases they all tell the same . Thanks

Comment: I already told you which book to read. It's not a Delphi book but that's irrelevant. What you need is a grounding in concurrent programming. And sadly OTL does not support D7.

Comment: I think you're wanting to much at the same time. Start by trying some of the suggestions in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029025/8029952#8029952), and keep away from pooling multiple types of worker threads for now.

Comment: Golez , I know but Simple implementation:
`
One thread per URI;
Each thread gets the data using one HTTP communication;
Then each thread parse the data;
Then use Synchronize to refresh the UI.
`
i know how to preassign URL , but i can't make 100 thread for 100 url's , i just wanna know what hot to retrieve url from some global list until all url's are done. But thanks for advice , will do that , it seems i have no other option....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you simply need to set up a [critical section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section).

This needs to be set up around the code segment which reads the next URL.  To do this you would typically place a semaphore at the start of the code so that only one thread can enter it at any time.  The semaphore is reset at the end of the code.  As each new thread sees the URL list has expired, then it terminates.

Typically semaphores are boolean, but they can be integers for example if you want to allow a specific number of threads to enter the region at any time.

In your case you can simply set up a global boolean variable (visible to all threads), say "fSemaphore".

At the start of the region, the thread checks the flag.  If it is false it sets it to true and enters the region (to get the next URL).
If it is true, then it loops  - e.g. repeat sleep(0) until (not fSemaphore).
When it exits the region it set fSemaphore := False;

Obviously you need to make sure you guard against a possible infinite loop scenario...

Answer (score 4):

You could have a thread-safe list of URLs to process, and a static-sized pool of worker threads each taking an unprocessed URL from the list at a time, processing it (downloading and parsing) and adding any found new URLs to the list, in a loop, as long as there are any unprocessed items in the list. Keep finished URLs in the list, only mark them as done, to avoid recursion.

Comment: "Keep finished URLs in the list, only mark them as done, to avoid recursion" - I would try to avoid this actually, because if you plan on launching many of these threads and the app could run for a long time, you could face this list becoming way too large, and eating up your memory. I usually make my threads "FreeOnTerminate" and just before I free I trigger a custom event "OnFinished" to alert its parent that it's about to be free'd, thus removing it from the list.

Comment: @JerryDodge Well, I still think you have to avoid recursion somehow, otherwise you'll end up processing the same URLs again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Define a 'TURI' class for the request URI, result, error message and anything else needed for the web query except for the component to be used for the URI access.  Descending from TObject shoud be fine. Create, initialize 100 of these and push them on a producer-consumer queue, (TObjectQueue, TCriticalSection and a semaphore should do fine). Hang a few TThreads off the queue that loop around and process the TURI instances until the queue is empty, whereupon they block.

You do not say what action you need taking with the processed TURI's - they will need freeing somewhere.  If you wish to notify the main thread, PostMessage the completed URI's and free them in the message-handler.

Terminate the threads?  Sure, if you really have to, then queue up some object that signals them to commit suicide, (a NIL maybe - the threads can check for 'assigned' just after popping the queue). When doing something like this, I oftem just leave the threads lying around even if I don't need to process any more URI during the app run - it's not worth the typing of terminating them.

Sadly, the Delphi examples and, I'm afraid, many textbooks, dont' get much further than suspend/resume control of threads, (don't do it), and 'TThread.Synchronize', 'TThread.WaitFor' and 'TThread.OnTerminate'.   If you get a textbook like that, take it outside and burn it - you will learn next-to-nothing good.